# How the smart wallets handles transactions that are only allowed for EOA?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

If after ERC-4337 the wallet is going to be a smart contract, how will it send transactions to smart contracts which only allow to have transactions with EOA?

Answer (score 2):

The user (everyone using the blockchain) will always need an External Owned Account because the private keys cannot be stored in the blockchain (they are private, right)?. The EOA is the only thing that allows you to make sure that no one else impersonates you (because only you hold the private key).

So I guess it does not change anything. The users will choose between using an EOA or the smart contract-based account, depending on whether they are interacting with a dapp or making a transfer of money.

The way I see it is that ERC-4337 is more related to payment systems(pay or receive payments). Even because VISA is the main "actor" pushing this. In fact, they have already started a pilot test on this. Check this article https://www.coindesk.com/business/2023/08/11/visa-eyes-mass-adoption-of-crypto-by-testing-method-of-paying-on-chain-gas-fees-through-fiat/

Also, when we make a DAPP we could from now on start to allow interaction from other smart contracts and manage the security issues related to that.